# How To Edit Char.js doughnut?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, reactjs

I want to make thin size of these doughnut which,is thickker. How to Edit it.?

I have tried to implemenet it and it sucessfully did worked but it's width size.How to Set it.?

Ts File.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-doughnut-chart',
  templateUrl: './my-doughnut-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-doughnut-chart.component.css']
})
export class MyDoughnutChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public doughnutChartLabels = ['Sales Q1', 'Sales Q2', 'Sales Q3', 'Sales Q4'];
  public doughnutChartData = [120, 150, 180, 90];
  public doughnutChartType = 'doughnut';
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

.html File

```
<div style="display: block">
  <canvas baseChart
              [data]="doughnutChartData"
              [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
              [chartType]="doughnutChartType"></canvas>
</div>
```

Thinner size of the round which is been given.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [docs](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#GeneralInfo), you can use `options`.

In your TS file you can add:

```
export class MyDoughnutChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public options = {
    cutoutPercentage: '10',
  }
```

then in your html file:

```
<div style="display: block">
<canvas baseChart
        [data]="doughnutChartData"
        [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
        [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
        [options]="options">
        </canvas>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qctzqm)

[image]